# Updating Python on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, installation, python

I am new to linux so I'm only just familiar with installing via the terminal. I currently have python 2.7.12 installed and I am trying to update it to python3 via the command

```
sudo apt-get install python3
```

however when i type in this command i am presented with 4 options

```
0 to upgrade
0 to newly install
0 to remove
5 to not upgrade
```

as you can see this is a problem and it doesn't recognize any commands i put in. I tried both 0 and 5 and they are both not found.

I'm running Ubuntu via virtualbox, not sure if this affects anything.

Comment: This suggests that you already have Python3 installed.You can use `synaptic` or `sudo apt show python3` to check its installation status.

Comment: There should also be a way to either use a verbose output and/or log file which contains the reason something wasn't updated.  Can you provide that information?

Comment: Did you try imagining that those options were correctly labelled 1 to 4, and then choosing one?

Comment: Btw, since you are new, I will make you aware of our [Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/) and [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) sister sites for possible future questions - although this question is (confusingly) also on topic here.

Answer (score 1):

You likely have Python v3 already installed. Try:

```
dpkg -l python3
```

You'll likely get something like this, which means python3 is already installed.

```
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                        Version            Architecture       Description
+++-===========================-==================-==================-============================================================
ii  python3                     3.5.1-3            amd64              interactive high-level object-oriented language (default pyt
```

On Ubuntu, the default Python is Python 2.7. If you want Python v3, use the `python3` command (or use `python3` in the script's [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix))). Do not replace `python` by Python v3 since too many systems scripts assume Python 2.7.